# Calculus differentiation — What did I do wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am learning Calculus with the book Calculus and Analytics Geometry, by George B. and Thomas, Jr., and I was doing the exercises on the Chapter 2.6 and using Wolfram Alpha to check my answer. I am told to differentiate $x(x^2+1)^{1/2}$, so I tried using The Product Rule and The Power Rule for Rational Numbers:

$\frac{d}{dt}x(x^2+1)^{1/2} = x\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{x^2+1}\frac{d}{dx}x = x\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} + \sqrt{x^2+1} = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}} + \frac{x^2+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}} + \frac{2x^2+2}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \frac{2x^2+x+2}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

But Wolfram Alpha gives

$\frac{2x^2 + 1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$

I am pretty sure I made a mistake, but I don't know where, sice it looks, to me, that I used the Product Rule and The Power Rule correctly. Hence my question: what did I do wrong?

As a note, I don't know if this question is allowed, and my LaTeX isn't very good.

Comment: Your error is in computing $$\frac d{dx}\sqrt{x^2+1}.$$ Your approach would be fine for $\frac d{dx}\sqrt{x+1}$ but you need the chain rule for the actual function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you. I used The Power Rule for Rational Number © wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you differentiated $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, you forgot to differentiate the $x^2$ term (chain rule); you should have got$$\frac{\cancel2x}{\cancel2\sqrt{x^2+1}}.\require{cancel}$$

Comment: Thank you. I used The Super-Duper Power Rule for Rational Number © wrong. I got the x's confused. Thanks a lot, and again.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.